# How to send data from Ardunio Nano using ENC28J60 to PHP

Tags: php, arduino, httpclient

I am trying to send the sensor data from Arduino Nano connected with ENC28J60 module for Ethernet connection, the Nano get the IP addresses from my router without any issue, but when I want to send the data to my php page it didn't work!

I tried the link in Postman and work but in Arduino Nano not work:

my code :

```
#include <UIPEthernet.h>
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>
#include "utility/logging.h"
EthernetClient client;
unsigned long next;
char serverAddress[] = "test.tech";  // server address
int port = 8080;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  uint8_t mac[6] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05};
//  Ethernet.init(3); Serial.println("cs pin");
 Ethernet.begin(mac);

  Serial.println("Initiliazed");
  Serial.print(("localIP: "));
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  Serial.print(("subnetMask: "));
  Serial.println(Ethernet.subnetMask());
  Serial.print(("gatewayIP: "));
  Serial.println(Ethernet.gatewayIP());
  Serial.print(("dnsServerIP: "));
  Serial.println(Ethernet.dnsServerIP());
  next = 0;
 

}
HttpClient client1 = HttpClient(client, serverAddress, port);
void loop()
{
  Serial.println("making GET request");
  client1.get("/Sensor/insert.php?temp=20&time=2020-08-10 19:58:46&Date=2020-08-10&Clock=19:58:46");
  int statusCode = client1.responseStatusCode();
  String response = client1.responseBody();
  Serial.print("Status code: ");
  Serial.println(statusCode);
  Serial.print("Response: ");
  Serial.println(response);
  Serial.println("Wait five seconds");
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about what exactly is not working on the Arduino side?  Are you getting any errors or output at all?  Are the requests reaching the server? Check the web server access log to verify you are receiving requests and also double check the error log to see if PHP has a problem with something.  You could also capture the request with Wireshark or similar method (tcpdump/netcat) and see what the request contains which may help identify the issue.  Things like missing Accept headers can cause interesting issues.

Comment: Actually I tried to post the data through postman and it works fine ! but still don't know the problem.

Comment: Clearly the requests are not the same... or your Arduino is not connected to the network.  Get the request payload from the Arduino as previously described and compare to postman.  I suspect it's something simple like a missing `Accept: *` header on the Arduino side but there is no way for me to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all:

this code it works with me using ENC28J60 and aI can send the data to PHP server, and I hope some one will find it usefull:

```
#include <Time.h>               //http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_Time.html
#include <TimeLib.h> //TimeLib library is needed https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time

#include <UIPEthernet.h> //UIPE ETHERNT LIBRARY FOR THE ETHERNET MODULE ENC28J60
#define DHTPIN 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 22  (AM2302), AM2321

#define DEBUG // TURN DEBUGGING ON OR OFF, TO TURN IT OFF JUST COMMENT THIS LINE
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
/* ETHERNET SETTINGS
ARDUINO UNO PINS USED FOR THE ENC28J60 MODULE: 10=CS, 11=MOSI, 12=MISO, 13=SCK
THE ETHERNET MAC ADDRESS MUST BE UNIQUE IN THE PRIVATE LOCAL NETWORK
REMEMBER THAT THE MAC ADDRESS IS IN HEXADECIMAL FORMAT
IN THIS EXAMPLE WE USE THE FOLLOWING MAC ADDRESS : OE:96:03:38:94:92 */
byte mac[] = { 0x0E, 0x96, 0x03, 0x38, 0x94, 0x92 };
EthernetClient client; // CREATES A CLIENT WHICH CAN CONNECT TO A SPECIFIED INTERNET IP ADDRESS AND PORT
char server[] = "www.mydomain.tech"; /// IP ADDRESS OF THE LOCAL SERVER WE CONNECT AND SEND DATA TO
int  interval = 18000; // DELAY INTERVAL TO SAVE THE DATA IN THE DATABSE
long myinterval = 18000; //3 Minutes-> 180000ms INTERVAL BETWEEN DATA READINGS, I SET IT IN 6 SECONDS FOR TESTING PURPOSES
long previousMillis = 0;
int status = -2; // INITIALIZE THE CONNECTION STATUS VARIABLE
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); // OPEN SERIAL COMMUNICATIONS AND WAIT FOR A PORT TO OPEN
  Ethernet.begin(mac); // INITIALIZES THE ETHERNET LIBRARY AND NETWORK SETTINGS
  /* ETHERNET SERIAL PRINTS
  INFORMATION ABOUT CLIENTS IP ADDRESS, THE SUBNET MASK OF THE NETWORK, THE GATEWAYS
  IP ADDRESS AND FINALLY THE DNS SERVER IP ADDRESS WHICH IS THE SAME AS THE GATEWAYS IP
  THESE INFORMATION WILL ONLY BE VISIBLE WHEN DEBUGGING IS ON */
  dht.begin();

#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.println("Temperature Logger");
  Serial.println("*********************");
  Serial.print("IP Address   : ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  Serial.print("Subnet Mask  : ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.subnetMask());
  Serial.print("Default Gateway IP: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.gatewayIP());
  Serial.print("DNS Server IP     : ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.dnsServerIP());
#endif
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  // RESET ENC28J60 IN CASE OF FAILURE TO CONNECT WITH THE LOCAL SERVER
  if (!client.connect(server, 80)) {
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("Connection Failure: Resetting ENC28j60!");
#endif
    Enc28J60.init(mac); //RESET AND INITIALIZE THE ENC28J60 AND STARTS PACKET TRANSMISSION-RECEPTION
  } else {
    client.stop();
  }
  /* CONNECT TO THE SPECIFIED IP ADDRESS AND PORT
   IF A CONNECTION IS ESTABLISHED START SENDING DATA EVERY 3 MINUTES
   DATA WILL BE SENT AFTER THE FIRST 3 MINUTES
   ALSO WE CHECK THE STATUS OF THE SERVER
   THE FUNCTION CONNECT() RETURNS AN INT INDICATING CONNECTION STATUTS:
   SUCCESS (1)
   TIMED_OUT (-1)
   INVALID SERVER (-2)
   TRUNCATED (-3)
   INVALID RESPONSE (-4)*/
  status = client.connect(server, 80);
  if (status == 1) {
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("\nConnection Success");
#endif
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis > myinterval) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      //READ DATA FROM THE DHT11 SENSOR
      /* THE READ11() FUNCTION RETURNS:
      DHTLIB_OK (0): THE SENSOR SAMPLE AND ITS CHECKSUM ARE OK
      DHTLIB_ERROR_CHECKSUM (-1): THE CHECKSUM TEST FAILED. THIS MEANS THE DATA WAS RECEIVED BUT MAY NOT BE CORRECT
      DHTLIB_ERROR_TIMEOUT (-2): A TIME OUT OCCURRED AND COMMUNICATION HAS FAILED
      BELOW WE CHECK THE STATUS OF THE SENSOR */
#ifdef DEBUG
      
#endif
      // PRINT THE HUMIDITY AND TEMPERATURE VALUES IN THE SERIAL MONITOR
#ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.print("\nValues: ");
      Serial.print(dht.readHumidity(), 1);
      Serial.print(",\t");
      Serial.println(dht.readTemperature(), 1);
      Serial.println("Connected...sendingData");
#endif
      // MAKE A HTTP REQUEST
      // SPECIFY THE PHP FILE LOCATION IN THE SERVER
      //PRINT DATA TO THE SERVER THE CLIENT IS CONNECTED TO
      //STRUCTURE: "GET /filepath/yourfile.php?"
      client.print( "GET /temptest/write_data.php?");
       client.print("temp=");
      client.print(dht.readTemperature(), 1); //THE VALUE TO WRITE IN THE DATABSE FOR TEMPERATURE
                 client.print("&&");
      client.print("hum="); //DATABASE VARIABLE IS USED
      client.print(dht.readHumidity(), 1); //THE VALUE TO WRITE IN THE DATABSE FOR HUMIDITY

      client.println( " HTTP/1.1");
      client.print( "Host: " );
      client.println(server);
      client.println( "Connection: close" );
      client.println();
      client.println();
      client.stop(); // DISCONNECT FROM THE SERVER
      delay(interval); //SOME INTERVAL FOR THE DATA TO BE WRITTEN IN THE DATABASE
    }
  }
  // IN CASE OF A TIME_OUT
  else if (status == -1) {
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("Connection Timed Out !");
#endif
  }
  // IN CASE OF AN INVALID SERVER
  else if (status == -2) {
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("Invalid Server !");
#endif
  }
  // IN CASE OF TRUNCATION
  else if (status == -3) {
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("Truncated !");
#endif
  }
  // IN CASE OF AN INVALID RESPONSE
  else if (status == -4) {
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("Invalid Response !");
#endif
  }
  // IN CASE OF AN UNKNOWN ERROR
  else {
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("Unknown Error !");
#endif
  }
}
```